# Use elements of array as names for expand_grid in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Im trying to use expand grid in a function.

Suppose:

```
key <- c("a", "g", "t", "c")
asd <- c("A", "B", "D")

for(i in asd){
  df = expand_grid(i = key)
}
```

What returns is:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  i    
  <chr>
1 a    
2 g    
3 t    
4 c
```

What I want is:

```
# A tibble: 64 x 3
     A    B     C
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 a     a     a    
 2 a     a     g    
 3 a     a     t    
 4 a     a     c    
 5 a     g     a    
 6 a     g     g    
 7 a     g     t    
 8 a     g     c    
 9 a     t     a    
10 a     t     g    
# ... with 54 more rows
```

Which is for each element of my array to be the `name` and for the `key` to be the value.

In my minimum reproducible code to obtain this I should write:

```
df = expand_grid("A" = key,
                 "B" = key,
                 "C" = key)
```

But for the sake of what I want to do, which is a function, I want for "A" "B" "C"...."n" to be created based on another function. For the values of the returned array to be used as the names in expand grid.

Comment: You overwrite `df` every pass in the loop, so it will only hold the last value you assigned to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `rep`licate the vector, set the names and `invoke` the `expand_grid`

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
out <- setNames(rep(list(key), length(asd)), asd) %>%
     invoke(expand_grid, .)
```

---

If we need a `for` loop to do this, initialize a `data.frame/tibble` with the `vector` first and then update that dataset on each iteration

```
df <- tibble(!!asd[1] := key)
for(i in asd[-1]) df <- expand_grid(df, !! i := key)
```

---

The `base R` `expand.grid` can be directly applied on a `list` of `vector`s

```
expand.grid(setNames(rep(list(key), length(asd)), asd) )
```

Comment: It worked! In 12 minutes I can upvote your answer. Can you tell me HOW you learned this? Im trying to get better at coding.

Comment: @PabloRodriguez  thanks. Your code is kind of applying `expand_grid` on a single vector at a time and this gets replaced in each iteration.  Thus, it didn't work.

Comment: It throws "The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol" when I run this second part

Comment: @PabloRodriguez it is working fine for me.  Maybe you have an older version of `dplyr/tibble` packages